# Is the backend always required in web applications?

Tags: backend

In the development of a website that offers only static content, the backend aspect is necessary? It can be useful for optimize some aspects?

Or is the backend only needed to handle authentications, dynamic content, etc.?

Comment: If you see no purpose in a backend you probably don't need one. A backend could optimize stuff in the sense that e.g. searching a file of a few 100Mb can be done faster on a server than sending the file to the client to do client side searching.

Answer (score 0):

A server is needed for back-end scripting and for storage of user data or objects like file uploads.

If you really only need static HTML + CSS + client-side JavaScript, you can run a site without a server by using cloud storage such as an Amazon Web Services S3 bucket.  AWS S3 can handle the HTTP/S GET requests without you running any kind of server, and Route 53 can map it to a custom domain like [www.mycompany.com](http://www.mycompany.com)

Microsoft Azure and Google Cloud may offer similar serverless storage-based websites.

Answer (score 0):

Does your static website store data or process business logic?  If not, it doesn't need a backend.

Reference:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frontend_and_backend

> In software architecture, there may be many layers between the hardware and end user. The front is an abstraction, simplifying the underlying component by providing a user-friendly interface, while the back usually handles data storage and business logic.